# put data into null Map

Tags: java, collections, dictionary

I've stumbled upon this weird thing in Java. While coding I've accidentally forgot to instantiate the Map. While putting data into it, everything was error free, but when getting them I got obvious NullPointerException. Here is a code snippet I used:

```
public class Loader {
   private static Map<String, Object> map;
   public static load() {
       //...
       // read lines and put them into map
       map.put(line, new Object()); // <-- NO ERROR
       //...
   }

   public static parse(){
       //...
       for(...){
           map.get(key); //<-- ERROR on map (NullPointerException)
       }
       //...
   }
}
```

The provided code is stub, the main purpose is to demonstrate weird map behavior. So why is it possible to insert data to null?
I'm using Java *1.6.0_29*.

Please note this code is complete, map is not initialized anywhere else; the code is complete.

Comment: Either a) you map is not null by the time you reach `map.put` or b) you never execute that line.

Comment: Why do you think your `load` method is ever called?

Comment: What if you try to `sysout` the map before and after `map.put` and `map.get`?

Comment: it has to definitly give nullPointer exception on map.put line. pls check again.

Comment: @assylias you were right the code never executed, I run it on particular data set which was not general enough.

Comment: @jnovacho Have a break, have a kitkat ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel dumb. As @assylias pointed out, the code where the put happen never executes. It was quite deep in for-each cycle, which was not executing due to previous bug. I feel ashamed.

Answer (score 0):

Briefly, you can't do this. I suspect instead that the exception thrown during the `map.put()` is being *swallowed* somewhere and you're not seeing it.

e.g.

```
try {
    (new Loader).load();
}
catch (Exception e) {
   // swallowed with no info here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is NOT complete... or perhaps, you are running a previous compiled version of your code.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the problem with the IDE or JDK you're using or it could be your code,because when I tried to replicate your case a java.lang.Error exception was thrown at compile time with the message that local variable map is not initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Either "map" is instantiated or the "put" line is unreachable.